# Shared drive/Folder issue

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, shared-folders

I have over 6 computers that are not listed on a domain, just normal local logins. There is one computer which is called User-PC which has a RAID Array. We also have another computer called TV-PC which runs Media Center and records our tv. Both of these computers have shared folders. From 5 out of 6 computers I can access the drives though from my laptop running over Wifi (Matts-Computer) I can't access any other device on the network. I have other computers running on the network that share and access shared folders fine. I have a shared drive on the laptop and everyone on the drive can access it. When I try to access any drive or folder that is shared from the laptop it tells me that I do not have access to the resource. I tried to create a homegroup on the network and I can see the other computers on the network I can open them and it shows the Documents Photos Music folders but when I try to open them nothing happens. The laptop is running Windows 7 Home Premimum x64. The only other 64 bit computer is the TV-PC and it runs Win 7 Pro.

Comment: In order to get some activity here, you might want to [edit] this to be a little less confusing. As it stands, this is one big run on paragraph which is difficult to understand exactly where you are going and it doesn't appear to have a question. If you do a search, there are lots of questions/answers on Superuser about connecting computers in a network environment.